# How to move a Vue component around without loosing its state

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a Vue3 wrapper component that implements a magnification feature in a dashboard. It displays an inner Vue component in two different ways. One is inline and the other is in a full-page pop-up for magnification. The gist of the template (I'm using Vuetify) is:

```html
<template>
  <v-card>
    <!-- normal location -->
    <component v-if="!full_page" :is="innerComponent" />
    <!-- magnified full-page version -->
    <v-dialog v-if="full_page">
      <v-card>
        <component :is="innerComponent" />
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

The above works in general, except that there are two different components in play. This means that if the non-magnified component has internal state then that is lost when switching to the magnified version. I see threee options:

- guarantee that all state, even transient one, is maintained external to the component
- reach into the component to clone state
- ensure Vue *moves* the component from one spot in the DOM to the other

My question is whether the third option is possible?

Comment: Just to mention it, you can also enable proper full screen mode for single elements. Use the useFullscreen from the vueUse library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Vue 3 you can use [Teleport component](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/teleport.html) to move a component around.
You can do like that:

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<Teleport :to="position ? '#div1' : '#div2'">
  <YourComponent/>
</Teleport>
```

An important note is that

> The teleport `to` target must be already in the DOM when the 
> component is mounted.

So you need some extra work to make it work with your own code.

[Live demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)